# Fast synchronous server requests with JS

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I would like to be able to make synchronous server requests for a game I plan on making. I've used AJAX's synchronous calls in the past sparingly because they are slow and I know that AJAX isn't cut out for this sort of task.

My reason for this is because I want it to be (as much as possible) hack-proof. For example, if a person buys an item. It will send a request to the server that they wish to buy the item and on that end it will check if they have enough of the currency and then send back if it's OK to allow them to buy it. Using this example, it'd obviously be a pain if it took several seconds each time you try to buy something.

The client side would be HTML5/JS and the server side would be PHP/SQL. What would be the best method to achieve this? Before anyone says "show me your code": I'm not asking for help on fixing something broken. I'm asking for a suggestion on the best way to access a server quickly and synchronously. If it isn't possible faster, then such an answer would suffice.

Comment: Unfortunately, this question will pull in opinions, which is one of the criteria for closing the question. There is no "absolute" solution for this, just a mix of generic optimizations. It really depends on a lot of factors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start by building the most basic approach: simple PHP script with minimal dependencies that only loads what is required to validate the request, connect to database, and make the query so it can return the result.

Then test its performance. If that's insufficient, I'd start looking at [websockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) or other technology stacks for just the fast-access portions (maybe node.js?).

Answer (score 1):

Making the request run synchronously doesn't make it faster. It just means that the browser is going to become unresponsive until the request is complete. Making it fast is a matter of writing your server-side code such that it can run quickly, and without any details we can't tell you how to do that.

Comment: I figured it needed to be synchronous precisely so other things couldn't happen before it returned. I did not assume synchronous would expedite the process, but rather than it needs to respond before they do other things. Using my example: if they can't afford the item, it needs to tell them they can't. If it was asynchronous and they attempted to buy something else, things could get messy.

Comment: There are other, simpler ways of preventing a user from doing things while an action is pending. Displaying a modal dialog using Javascript is an easy one.